# OpenGLES: How to get the lower 8 bits of an int

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to split a 16 bit integer into two unsigned bytes and then recombine them inside a shader to use as a position. However, OpenGLES reserves & and <<, so I've had to come up with a couple of tricks in order to retrieve each section.

```
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D u_Positions;
uniform sampler2D u_Velocities;

// uniform vec2 vpSize;

void main() {
    vec2 coord = gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(256.0, 256.0);
    vec4 position = texture2D(u_Positions, coord);
    vec4 velocity = texture2D(u_Velocities, coord);
    vec2 real_Position = vec2((position.r * 256.0 * 256.0) + (position.g * 256.0),(position.b * 256.0 * 256.0) + (position.a * 256.0));
    real_Position.x += ((velocity.r * 256.0) + velocity.g) * 256.0;
    real_Position.y += ((velocity.b * 256.0) + velocity.a) * 256.0;
    vec4 color = vec4(1.0);
    color.r = float(int(real_Position.x) / 256) / 256.0;
    color.g = mod(real_Position.x, 256.0) / 256.0;
    color.b = float(int(real_Position.y) / 256) / 256.0;
    color.a = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

So I take the red component multiply by 256 to put it in the range of 1-256 and then shift it to left 8 bits by multiplying by 256. Then I do the same for the lower half without shifting then add them together.

The problem I have however, is converting back into the [0,1] range. The top half im just shifting to the right 8 bits and then dividing by 256. However for the bottom half since there is no and I use modulo 256 to get the lower 8. But for some reason I end up with random 1's attached to it.

So I want to use 960 for my x component I would end up with 3 red 195 green instead of 192 green. If I want to use 0 I end up with my position being 1. The lower 8 bits off. What am I doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you'd have to multiply with 255 instead of 256 (in some cases). why? because if you multiply a [0,1] value range with 256 you get a [0,256] value range -> 257 individual values -> overflow (largest 0-based 8bit number is 255)

EDIT: seems like a classical 1-off error. if you divide a [0,256] range through 256, you get a [1/256,1] range. eg.

```
color.r = float(int(real_Position.x) / 256) / 255.0;
```

should be the correct calculation in this case. also, if you multiply a [0,1] value with 256 and assign this value to a byte, the result would be the same until you actually hit 1, where the byte would be 0 again. why that? (254/255) * 256 = 254.99 = 254 (because of int rounding), but 1*256=256 (byte range is [0,255]). so everywhere you are converting between color [0,1] floats and bytes, you have to multiply/divide with 255 while everywhere you convert between 8-bit and 16-bit values you have to multiply/divide with 256.

in general equations:

```
lb=w%256    //lower byte from 16bit
hb=w/256    //higher byte from 16bit
w=lb+hb*256 //16bit from bytes
b=f*255     //byte from [0,1] float (0->0, 1->255)
f=b/255.0   //[0,1] float from byte (0->0, 255->1)
```